# Is it a bad translation to consider a product feature a "característica de producto"?

Tags: traducción

I've had some discussion about if *product feature* could be translated to *característica de producto* per se.

Some coworkers have argued that *característica* might refer to something more tied to *how the product is* rather than to *what it does*.

In English, it's very common to use *feature* to describe both some given behavior in a product and anything that makes it stand out.

Disclamer: I'm Spanish, but I want your advice to ensure that I'm using the word *característica* when I translate it from *feature* in the particular case of *product feature*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acuerdo a la RAE Característico,ca:

> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al carácter.
> 2. adj. Dicho de una cualidad: Que da carácter o sirve para distinguir a alguien o algo de sus semejantes. U. t. c. s. f.

Con la acepción 2 tenemos que si el producto tiene una cualidad que sirve para destacarlo o diferenciarlo, esa cualidad la podemos llamar característica, por lo tanto no importa si esa cualidad es algo que "es" o algo que "hace".

Por lo anterior el uso de **característica** en español es igual al uso de **feature** en inglés y pude usarse como traducción válida.

La única observación que tengo es que sería necesario un poco más de contexto para saber si debes escribir "característica **de** producto" o "característica **del** producto" ya que en todos los ejemplos que se me ocurren en este momento lo correcto sería usar **del**.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Pensaba que aquí se preguntaba/respondía en inglés. Sin recurrir a la RAE pensaba igual, pero no soy filólogo, así que no me la quería jugar.

Comment: El contexto es el típico a nivel comercial. Una empresa vende un producto con características. Por ejemplo, un gestor de clientes y contactos, tiene las características "alta/modificación/baja de clientes" y "notificaciones de actualizaciones a clientes".

Comment: Oops....usualmente contestamos en el mismo idioma de la pregunta, pero me quedé con que eras Español y me olvidé de contestar en inglés.

Comment: Te he dado un poco el contexto en el comentario anterior ;)

Comment: Me suena que **de** podría ser correcto en algún contexto, pero no se me ocurre ninguno en este momento. Todos los ejemplos que pienso usarían **del**. Si adicionas el texto en inglés tal vez podamos dar algunas otras opciones.

Comment: In the context of software and product development, when talking about product features - a discrete piece of a product that delivers value to the user, and being a product a bundle of features -, the most accurate translation for feature is "funcionalidad".

// *RAE* *Funcionalidad*: 1. f. Cualidad de funcional.
*Funcional*: 2. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Diseñada u organizada atendiendo, sobre todo, a la facilidad, utilidad y comodidad de su empleo.

// I'm a Spanish Product Manager with 10 years of experience, working in an english-speaking company.

Answer (score 7):

This is a common discussion in software development when a Spanish translation effort is underway, which is why I will provide my two cents in English, despite the original poster's native language.

> Is it a bad translation to consider a product feature a "*característica de producto*"?

Before beginning to address the use of "*característica*" as "*feature*", please notice that proper Spanish would be:

- Característica **del** producto (*feature of **the** product* - A specific product previously referred)
- Característica **de un** producto (*feature of **a** product* - A general product)
- Característica de **X** (*feature of product **X*** - A named product or brand)

So, if you just used "*producto*" as a placeholder for a product name, then it is a proper translation; however, if that was not the case, "**de**" should be replaced for "**del**" or "**de un**", depending if you are referring to a particular product or a product in general.

After that has been cleared up, let's answer the question:
`No, it is not a bad translation.`

As a matter of fact, take a look at the following article of Microsoft related to the features of a SharePoint publishing site in [English](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Features-enabled-in-a-SharePoint-Online-publishing-site-3ab3810c-3c2c-4361-9d0e-0cbe666ea0b0) and then its translation in [Spanish](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Caracter%C3%ADsticas-habilitadas-en-un-sitio-de-publicaci%C3%B3n-de-SharePoint-Online-3ab3810c-3c2c-4361-9d0e-0cbe666ea0b0). You will notice Microsoft translates "*features*" as "*características*".

Initially, I considered the translation to be odd and had the same misgivings your co-workers brought up. It also just didn't feel right. This made me think of alternatives to describe the functionality which was provided by a "*feature*".

Here is a list of possible alternatives that I came up with:

- Rasgos (*Features*)
- Utilidades (*Benefits*)
- Atributos (*Attributes*)
- Aptitudes (*Features*, *Aptitudes*)
- Atribuciones (*Attributions*)
- Disposiciones (*Features*, *Aptitudes*, *Dispositions*)
- Capacidades (*Capabilities*)
- Comportamientos (*Behaviors*)
- Aspectos (*Aspects*)
- Propiedades (*Properties*)
- Funcionalidades (*Sets of Functionality*)

These options can also be paired with "*funcional*" (*functional*) to make them more specific for software products:

- Rasgos funcionales
- Utilidades funcionales
- Atributos funcionales
- Aptitudes funcionales
- Atribuciones funcionales
- Disposiciones funcionales
- Capacidades funcionales
- Comportamientos funcionales
- Aspectos funcionales
- Propiedades funcionales

Regarding more tangible products: In the past, boxes would include a label that would list features of products as "*con*" which means "*with*" and "*incluye*", which means "*includes*".

Here are options included in the past to label a list of features in a product's box:

- Cualidades (*Qualities*, as mentioned by [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/6915/rodrigo))
- Bondades (*Positive aspects*, *advantages*)
- Ventajas (*Advantages*)
- Beneficios (*Benefits*)

Comment: Qué respuestas tan buenas escribes, Jorge.

Comment: Hola, es una muy buena respuesta. +1. He seleccionado la otra porque al fin y al cabo viene a transmitir lo mismo salvo en lo extenso y detallado de tu propia respuesta, que no es nada despreciable: ¡todo lo contrario! Gracias por el esfuerzo y todo sumado será útil para la comunidad en general.

Comment: @fedorqui Muchas gracias por el reconocimiento, fedorqui.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Gracias, Matías, mi intención no era que cambiaras tu selección de la mejor respuesta sino proveer una que se pueda usar de referencia para aquellos miembros de la comunidad que se encuentren en tu posición a futuro. Tampoco creí que sería justo sólo traducir las otras respuestas por lo que procuré ser lo más claro posible para aquellos cuyo primer lenguaje es el inglés.

Comment: @Jorge Sí sí, no quise decir eso, sólo me excusaba yo ;)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Matías, no te preocupes, no hay nada de qué excusarte. Sólo quería reiterar que no esperaba algo en particular de tu parte, no estaba comentando que pensaba que eso era lo que estabas implicando. :)

Answer (score 4):

En el ámbito comercial tal vez *features* no se refiera a cualquier característica, sino especialmente a las *características positivas* o *distintivas* del producto. En tal caso hay traducciones alternativas que se enfocan en aquello, aunque no sean literales:

> prestaciones del producto
>
> atractivos del producto
>
> cualidades del producto
>
> características especiales del producto

Comment: Me gusta "prestaciones" que podría decirse en inglés "product capabilities"

Answer (score 0):

En español, un programa o dispositivo tiene **funciones**. El término puede presentar conflicto con el concepto de matemática y lenguajes de programación, pero es un termino usado por la mayor parte de la población, por lo cual tiene prioridad sobre los términos internos al desarrollo.

—¿Qué funciones tiene el celular?
—Puede llamar, navegar por internet, y pedir taxis.