# ¿Es lo mismo "función" que "funcionalidad" en el ámbito de las características de un producto?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, informática, diferencias-entre-palabras

En dos preguntas de este sitio se ha hablado del concepto inglés *feature*:

- [How to translate "feature" in "Is it a feature or a bug"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23088/1674)
- [Is it a bad translation to consider a product feature a "característica de producto"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19176/1674)

En la primera, la [respuesta de Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23090/1674) dice: *¿Es esto parte de la **funcionalidad** (de la aplicación) o es un bug?*, a lo que [Gustavson comentó](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23088/how-to-translate-feature-in-is-it-a-feature-or-a-bug/23090#comment37184_23090) *Also just "función", I think*.

La [respuesta de Tomás Zubiri](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/34447/1674) a la seguna pregunta indica *En español, un programa o dispositivo tiene **funciones**.*

Ambas palabras aparecen en el diccionario (destaco solamente las acepciones relevantes):

> [**función**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=funci%C3%B3n)
>   *Del lat. functio, -ōnis.*
>
> 1. f. Capacidad de actuar propia de los seres vivos y de sus órganos, y de las máquinas o instrumentos.
>
> 2. f. Tarea que corresponde realizar a una institución o entidad, o a sus órganos o personas.

Y luego:

> [**funcionalidad**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=funcionalidad)
>
> 1. f. Cualidad de funcional.
>
> > [**funcional**](https://dle.rae.es/funcional?m=form)
> >
> > 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la función o a las funciones. Competencia, procedimiento funcional. Dependencia, enlace funcional.
> >
> > 2. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Diseñada u organizada atendiendo, sobre todo, a la facilidad, utilidad y comodidad de su empleo.
> >
> > 3. adj. Dicho de una obra o de una técnica: Eficazmente adecuada a sus fines.

Por tanto, entenderíamos que *funcionalidad* es la capacidad de hacer alguna función. Por ello, decir que un programa tiene una función o decir que tiene una funcionalidad serían dos maneras de decir lo mismo: decir que hace X o decir que tiene capacidad de hacer X. Como si de un niño dijéramos que *sabe andar* o *tiene capacidad de andar*. Sin embargo, tirando de este último ejemplo parecería que lo primero asegura que lo hace, mientras lo segundo indicaría que está preparado para hacerlo, sin saber si ya lo hace o no.

Por ello: en el campo de la tecnología, ¿es lo mismo decir que se tiene una función y decir que se tiene una funcionalidad?

Answer (score 1):

En la entrada para *functionality* en wiktionary, parte de la definición es "set of functions".  Eso me parece correcto.  O sea que es la colección de todas las funciones que puede realizar un aparato.

"Feature" es un poco más genérico.  Es una de las características de un producto,  sí.  Pero es una característica favorable,  algo que resulta en la aceptación del producto.

No se me ocurre una palabra en español que corresponda exactamente a "feature".

Comment: Cualidad: Característica que se considera buena o positiva. https://dle.rae.es/?w=cualidad ;-P

Comment: > No se me ocurre una palabra en español que corresponda exactamente a "feature". «prestación» es una.